# The node_modules Volume Trick when building an angular app with docker

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, node-modules

I try to use Docker and use it with an angular App. I follow this steps : https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-an-angular-app/

But i did not understand the trick with the node_modules. I know that we need to run docker with the follow parameters `-v ${PWD}:/app` to bind the host files in the container. But i do not get the part with the parameter `-v /app/node_modules`. How can Docker create the volume with a copy of the `/app/node_modules` from the container if it's hidden by the host bind ?

Answer (score 3):

The link mentioned in your question had already answer to your question.
**Since we want to use the container version of the “node_modules”** folder, we configured another volume: `-v /app/node_modules`. You should now be able to remove the local `node_modules` flavour.

In simple, you want to use everything from the host, the complete code but not the `node_modules`. so you just mapped with an empty directory of the host so this trick will able your container to use the container `node_modules` not the host `node_modules`.

There are many factors, some node_modules are Host depended like x509 so it will not work inside Linux container if your Host OS is the window.

the first trick, install modules in docker build time

```
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
```

second during running container,

```
docker run --name test -it -v ${PWD}:/app -v /app/node_modules -p 4201:4200 --rm test-app
```

After running your container if you delete host node_modules your container will still work as it will be using container node_modules.

In simple word, remove host node_modules and run

```
docker run --name test -it -v ${PWD}:/app  -p 4201:4200 --rm test-app
```

It will fail to run because container `/app` complete directory override by host.

The work arround is simple the trick that you missed to understand.

```
docker run --name test -it -v ${PWD}:/app -v /app/node_modules -p 4201:4200 --rm test-app
```

It will prevent `node_modules`  of the container to be overridden.

Comment: this is workaround  to use a data volume to store all the node_modules, as data volumes copy in the data from the built docker image before the worker directory is mounted.